# PHP two arrays in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

Okay so basically what I have a sock_id and a charity_id,  there are 4 options for socks and 2 for charity. the user can pick multiple socks and charities, so what i have right now is:
sock_id = 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 
charity_id = 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 
what i want is :
sock_id = 1 2 3 4 
charity_id = 1 2 1 2 
here is my code:

```
 $sockList = $_POST['sock_list'];
 $charityList = $_POST['charity'];
foreach($sockList as $s){
foreach($charityList as $c){
$sql = "INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id)  VALUES('$donor', '$s', '$c')";
$conn->query($sql);
 echo "$sql";
}
}
```

Output:

INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id) VALUES('8', '1','1')

INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id) VALUES('8', '1', '2')

INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id) VALUES('8', '2','1')

INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id) VALUES('8', '2', '2')

here is what the table looks like:

[image: Table]

here is what i want:

[image: table2]

if you need more information let me know but i know the problem just lies within this code and im pretty sure its a for loop issue

Comment: can you include the output of `echo "$sql";` ?

Comment: this output is just when a user selects 2 socks and both charties

Comment: You posted some code an you are probably expecting us to fix it without even telling what is the problem with it.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use **[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: i did say what the problem is, in my code axiac, the table is duplicating the sock_id for each charity_id inserted, so sock_id = 1 1 2 2 3 3 and charity = 1 2 1 2 1 2, what i want is sock_id = 1 2 3 and charity = 1 2 1. If you dont understand what im asking thats one thing, but i am telling you the problem

Comment: $sockList ,$charityList  what it contain?

Comment: Of course you get the same sock_id for the different charity_ids. You're inserting the the same sock_id in each iteration for the charity_id (the inner loop). You get different combinations though. You should show us what the table rows looks like (what you get and what you expect). You're examples are very unclear the way you've written them.

Comment: you're using nested loops, so of course for each value in sock_id, you'll iterate the charity list. I suggest rethinking your code design, your code is correct,but it's not designed for your use case, *good luck*.

Comment: contains the selection of checklist values that the user submits

Comment: I think your form (or where you get the data from) would need to be restructured a bit. Currently, you have two arrays without any relations, unless `sock_id` and `charity_id` will always be the same. If not, it's impossible to know what items goes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($sockList);$i++){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id)  VALUES('$donor', $sockList[$i],  $charityList[$i])";
 $conn->query($sql);
 echo "$sql";
 }
```

Comment: That works for two but then prints the error: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in 
INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id) VALUES('10', '3', '')
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in 
INSERT INTO donor_sock(Donor_id, Sock_id, Charity_id) VALUES('10', '4', '') when i enter in 4 choices socks

Comment: $sockList ,$charityList both array need to be of same size please make sure  that, that mean every sock_id should have charity_id then it ll work

Comment: is there no way to duplicate the charity_id inserts so that it fills out the rest of the table?

Comment: it ll be blank then, is it fine?

Comment: unfortunately no, it has to fill out and not be blank, what you typed definitely works, no it just needs to duplicate

Comment: got it! used array_merge to merge the contents so that it duplicates when needed